# How to improve YOLOv3 detection time? (OpenCV + Python)

Tags: python, opencv, darknet

I'm using YOLOv3 custom trained model with OpenCV 4.2.0 compiled with CUDA. When I'm testing code in Python I'm using OpenCV on GPU (GTX1050 Ti) but detection on single image (416px x 416px) takes 0.055 s (~20 FPS). My config file is set to small object detection, because I need to detect ~ 10px x 10px objects on 2500px x 2000px images so I split original image into 30 smaller pieces. My goal is to reach 0.013 s (~80 FPS) on 416px x 416px image. Is it possible in Python with OpenCV? If not, how to do it in proper way?

PS. Currently detection takes like 50% of CPU, 5GB RAM and 6% GPU.

Comment: Doesn't YOLOv3 work on smaller sizes? There's a YOLOv3-320 that should work on 320 by 320 images and is faster, not sure if you'd want to use that instead?

Comment: 320 x 320 images means that I will need to perform detection on 50 splitted images, so I will need 125 FPS. I don't know if that is possible. First of all I don't know if Python with OpenCV is a good way to go.

Comment: I mean if you have CUDA set up its not a Python issue. You could try threading it, as it doesn't seem like your GPU is being hammered by inferences.

Comment: Have you thought of using YOLOv5?

Comment: @MZ What about Python GIL? I could use multiprocessing, but I'm concerned about RAM. I only have 16GB and single process use ~5GB.


@yuRa According to YOLOv3 / 4 developer GitHub -

`The latest version - YOLOv4, with paper, with URLs from official repository, and with the best Accuracy/Speed among all known algorithms.

YOLOv5-Ultralytics - is just a name, model is worse than YOLOv4, without improvements, without a scientific article, and with fake comparisons in a couple of blogs.`

Comment: I'm curious why it takes 5gb of ram, if you place the image in shared memory the largest components shouldn't need to be replicated. I'm not sure what your concern with the Python GIL is – when jobs are sent to the GPU the GIL is no longer a concern. But even with two threads on the same process it would be faster.

Comment: You mean multithreading on GPU? If so, CUDA don't allow that.

Comment: Are you sure you are using GPU on your code? If you wanna continue with CPU, you can decrease accuracy and increase speed or vice versa.

Comment: On CPU i have 0.5s, on GPU 0.05s. So yes, I'm using GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some of the preferred ways to improve *detection time* with already trained Yolov3 model are:**

- Quantisation: Run inference with INT8 instead of FP32. You can use this [repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/yolo2_light) for this purpose.
- Use Inference accelerator such as [TensorRT](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt) since you're using Nvidia's GPU. The tool includes good amount of inference oriented optimisations along with quantisation optimisations INT8 and FP16 to reduce detection time. This [thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/yolov3-with-tensorrt-5/68705) talks about Yolov3 inference with TensorRT5. Use [this](https://github.com/wang-xinyu/tensorrtx) repo for Yolov3 on TensorRT7.
- Use inference library such as [tkDNN](https://github.com/ceccocats/tkDNN), which is a Deep Neural Network library built with cuDNN and tensorRT primitives, specifically thought to work on NVIDIA Jetson Boards.

**If you're open to do the model training there are few more options other than the ones mentioned above:**

- You can train the models with tinier versions rather than full Yolo versions, of course this comes at the cost of drop in accuracy/mAP. You can train [tiny-yolov4](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4-tiny-custom.cfg) (latest model) or train [tiny-yolov3](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3-tiny_obj.cfg).
- Model Pruning - If you could rank the neurons in the network according to how much they contribute, you could then remove the low ranking neurons from the network, resulting in a smaller and faster network. Pruned yolov3 research [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11093v1) and it's [implementation](https://github.com/PengyiZhang/SlimYOLOv3). [This](https://github.com/Lam1360/YOLOv3-model-pruning) is another pruned Yolov3 implementation.